# ClipRRect not working properly using carousel inside listview(scrollview)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a carousel from the package https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider, inside my listview (scrollview). I want to make my images have a round corner border.

I used clipRRect and it works (clip corner image with round border). But something strange happens to my apps. Here my result, I upload to google drive, please download first
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YNRk3q87-wD080eNvLa9OQ1j2KytvaJW

And here my code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget menus(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21, vertical: 18),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Layanan favorit',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Lihat Semua',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: Color(0xFFFF2800)
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'Token Listrik',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_ELECTRICITY),
                ),
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'Pulsa',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_BALANCE),
                ),
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'Paket Data',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_DATA),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'Kereta Api',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_TRAIN),
                ),
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'e Money',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_EMONEY),
                ),
                IconMenu(
                  text: 'Pasca Bayar',
                  image: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_POSTPAID),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget offers(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Hot offers',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Lihat Semua',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      color: Color(0xFFFF2800)
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            child: CarouselOffers(),
          )

        ],
      ),
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: HomeAppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 21, 21, 18),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 11, 20, 11),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              child: Text(
                                  'Kasku Balance',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                            child: Text(
                                'Rp 2.000.000',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Icon(
                                  Icons.refresh,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0)),
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_TOPUP),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                                  child: Text(
                                      'Isi Saldo',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Color(0xFF231F20)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 1,
                            height: 54,
                            color: Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    child: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_PAY),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Bayar',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Color(0xFF231F20)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 1,
                            height: 54,
                            color: Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  child: SvgPicture.asset(ICON_TRANSFER),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Transfer',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Color(0xFF231F20)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
              ),

              menus(),
              offers(),
              news(),
              news2()

            ],

          ),
        ),

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              title: Text('Jelajah'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              title: Text('Layanan'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              title: Text('Transaksi'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              title: Text('Profile'),
            ),
          ],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class CarouselOffers extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _CarouselOffersState createState() => _CarouselOffersState();
}

class _CarouselOffersState extends State<CarouselOffers> {
  int _current = 0;

  List<Widget> widgets(){
    return ['https://cdn2.tstatic.net/lampung/foto/bank/images/bukalapak-promo-bulan-ramadan_20180511_135232.jpg', 'https://cdn2.tstatic.net/lampung/foto/bank/images/bukalapak-promo-bulan-ramadan_20180511_135232.jpg'].map((i) {
      return Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: Image.network(
                  i,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
          );
        },
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CarouselSlider(
          pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
          aspectRatio: 16/6,
          items: widgets(),
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _current = index;
            });
          },
          autoPlay: true,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: map<Widget>(widgets(), (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 6.0,
              height: 6.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 4.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

what is wrong with my code? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late answer.
Everything is fine when using real device. I do not know why ClipperRRect not working properly when using emulator (Genymotion).